# Go言語のパッケージインストールに失敗する

Tags: go

「Go」言語学習のため環境を整えテストコードを記載すると、
アラートメッセージが上がります。

```
The "go-outline" command is not available.  Use "go get -v github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline" to install.
```

指示の通りにアラートにある「Install All」を押しますが、
エラーが表示されインストールができません。
どのあたりの設定を見直せばよいのでしょうか？
（そこらにあるGo言語導入のサイトを一通り見たのですが、このインストール部分でエラーになっているケースがないので困っています。）

エラーメッセージを見るとファイルがないとの記載がありますが、
「https://github.com/mdempsky/gocode」などに、
アクセスが出来るので存在しているように思うのですが。

ちなみに`go get -u -v github.com/nsf/gocode`のコマンドを、
ターミナルから直接叩いてもダメでした。

なお目的はデバックが可能となり開発できるようなところまで、
もっていきたいです。

【**エラーメッセージ**】

```
Installing 12 tools at C:\Users\xxxx\go\bin


  gocode

Installing github.com/mdempsky/gocode FAILED

12 tools failed to install.

gocode:
Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe get -u -v github.com/mdempsky/gocode
github.com/mdempsky/gocode (download)
go: missing Git command. See https://golang.org/s/gogetcmd
package github.com/mdempsky/gocode: exec: "git": executable file not found in %PATH%
github.com/mdempsky/gocode (download)
go: missing Git command. See https://golang.org/s/gogetcmd
package github.com/mdempsky/gocode: exec: "git": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

(一番上のコマンドのだけ記載しています。)

【**サンプルコード**】

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main()  {
    fmt.Println("Go!!!")

}
```

【**環境 / 導入したツール**】
•Windows10 64bit
•Visual Studio Code 1.10.2
  --Go 0.8.0
  --Japanese Language Pack for Visual Studio 1.30.2
•Go 1.8

【**参考サイト**】
https://dev.classmethod.jp/go/visual-studio-code-golang-debug/

Comment: インストール先が `C:\Program Files` の下なんでしょうか？ 最近のBlog記事で出てくるのは `C:\Go` に入れているようですが。

Comment: あまり直下に置きたくなかったのでインストール時に`C:\Program Files`に変更いたしましたが、デフォルトの`C:\Go`でインストールしなおしました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーメッセージを読むと、Gitコマンドがインストールされていないか、 `%PATH%` の中に存在しないようです。

> go: missing Git command. See https://golang.org/s/gogetcmd
>   package github.com/mdempsky/gocode: exec: "git": executable file not found in %PATH%

このため、Windows版のGitコマンドをインストールすることで解決できそうです。
[Git - Downloads](https://git-scm.com/downloads)

Comment: Gitコマンドをインストールすることで該当のエラーが解消されました。但し別途違うエラーが発生しましたので、こちらはまた確認後質問し直すことにします。