# Go言語のパッケージインストールに失敗する２

Tags: go

「Go」言語学習のため環境を整えテストコードを記載すると、アラートメッセージが上がります。

```
'Some Go analysis tools are missing from your GOPATH.  Would you like to install them?
```

指示の通りにアラートにある「Install」を押しますが、エラーが表示されインストールができません。どのあたりの設定を見直せばよいのでしょうか？

## エラーメッセージ

```
    Installing 1 tool at C:\Users\xxxx\go\bin
  dlv

Installing github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv FAILED

1 tools failed to install.

dlv:
Error: Command failed: C:\Go\bin\go.exe get -u -v github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv
github.com/derekparker/delve (download)
# cd C:\Users\xxxx\go\src\github.com\derekparker\delve; git pull --ff-only
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

package github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv: exit status 1
```

## サンプルコード

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main()  {
    fmt.Println("Go!!!")

}
```

## 環境 / 導入したツール

- Windows10 64bit
- Visual Studio Code 1.10.2

  - Go 0.8.0
  - Japanese Language Pack for Visual Studio 1.30.2
- Go 1.8
- git 2.20.1

## 参考サイト

1. https://dev.classmethod.jp/go/visual-studio-code-golang-debug/
2. https://yuzu441.hateblo.jp/entry/2015/12/27/023040

## 考察

「github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv」にアクセスができないので、パスが問題なのではと考えています。

ただしこの設定はこちらで行っているものではないのですが、どこか意図的に設定を行う必要があるのでしょうか。

もしくは参考サイト２のようにローカル側に、リポジトリに関する初期設定が必要なのでしょうか？

Comment: `github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv` に対応するURLは https://github.com/go-delve/delve/tree/master/cmd/dlv で、こちらに問題はなさそうです。一度 `C:\Users\xxxx\go\src\github.com\derekparker\delve` というディレクトリを削除してから再度実行してみてください

Comment: delveディレクトリを削除して再取得をしたところ成功しました。その後VSCdoeから「デバック」→「デバックの開始」で、デバックコンソール上に「Go!!!」が出力されました。ありがとうございました！（URLはエイリアス等の設定が、なされているのでしょうか…。）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントの結果解決したようですが原因の考察を回答といたします。

今回、[@satckper](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/29050/satckper)氏の一つ前の[質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/52115)において、**Gitコマンドが存在せず、`go get`に失敗する**という現象が起きていました。このため、正常に依存ライブラリの取得が行われておらず、`There is no tracking information for the current branch.` というエラーメッセージが出ていたようです。

そこで、`git`コマンドをインストールした後に各ディレクトリを削除し、新しく取得し直したことで、今回のエラーが解決して無事に実行できたようです。